# Variable access in main function when returned by another function?

Tags: c

So I saw this code on the internet for reversing a string using recursion in C.

I understood the code except the part where the `reverse` function returns `str1` and then `str1` is printed in the `main` function. `str1` wasn't passed by reference, but only by address. So how come it prints the reversed string and not the original string when it is printed through `main` function?

```
void reverse(char str1[], int index, int size);

int main() {
    char str1[20];
    int size;

    printf("Enter a string to reverse: ");
    scanf("%s", str1);
    size = strlen(str1);
    reverse(str1, 0, size - 1);
    printf("The string after reversing is: %s\n", str1);
    return 0;
}

void reverse(char str1[], int index, int size) {
    char temp;
    temp = str1[index];
    str1[index] = str1[size - index];
    str1[size - index] = temp;
    if (index == size / 2) {
        return str1;
    } else {
        reverse(str1, index + 1, size);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

For starters the function showed by you is wrong. If an empty string is passed to the function like this

```
reverse(str1, 0, size - 1);
```

then the expression `size - 1` will be equal to `-1`. As result the function will have undefined behavior due to an attempt to access memory beyond the array in these statements

```
str1[index] = str1[size - index];
str1[size - index] = temp;
```

The function has two many parameters. String functions usually return pointer to the destination string. So it will be better if the function `reverse` also returns pointer to the string.

It can be defined simpler. For example

```
char * reverse(char *s, size_t n)
{
    if (!(n < 2))
    {
        char c = s[0];
        s[0] = s[n - 1];
        s[n - 1] = c;

        reverse(s + 1, n - 2);
    }

    return s;
}
```

And you can call it like

```
printf("The string after reversing is: %s\n", reverse( str1, strlen( str1) ));
```

As for you question then this declaration

```
void reverse(char str1[], int index, int size);
```

is equivalent to the following declaration

```
void reverse(char *str1, int index, int size);
             ^^^^^^^^^^
```

When an array is passed tp the function like this

```
reverse(str1, 0, size - 1);
```

then the array designator is converted to pointer to its first element. Within the function the array is not moved from one memory area to another memory area. It stays at the same address. Only the elements of the array are being changed. So after exiting the function the elements of the array will be modified but they will have the same addresses in memory as in the array before calling the function. In fact the array elements are passed to the function by reference that is by the pointer to the first element of the array.

Answer (score 1):

The function does not return anything, it receives the array as a pointer to its first element (the array *decays* into a pointer to its first element) and it performs the transposition in place.  Note that the declaration `void reverse(char str1[], int index, int size)` is equivalent to `void reverse(char *str1, int index, int size)`.

The code has multiple problems:

- It does not function for strings of even lengths. It even invokes undefined behavior on the empty string.
- It uses recursion for no decent reason.  A simple loop approach would have been simpler and have less bugs.
- It has a `return str1;` statement even though it is defined as `void`.

The function does not return anything, it receives the array as a pointer to its first element and performs the transposition in place.

Here is a simpler alternative:

```
#include <stdio.h>

char *reverse(char *str) {
    for (size_t i = 0, length = strlen(str); i < length / 2; i++) {
        char temp;
        temp = str[i];
        str1[i] = str1[length - i - 1];
        str1[length - i - 1] = temp;
    }
    return str;
}

int main(void) {
    char buf[100];

    printf("Enter a string to reverse: ");
    if (scanf("%s", buf) == 1) {
        printf("The string after reversing is: %s\n", reverse(buf));
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A reference of a variable is it's address or more correctly the variable that holds the address.

When you pass an object/variable by ref you acctualy pass it's address, in C you do it by passing the pointer of the variable while in c# for instance you need to declare "ref" when you passing an argument to a function.